# MySQL: Shuffle a limited query result?

Tags: sql, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple Random Samples from a (My)Sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249301/simple-random-samples-from-a-mysql-database)

Hi!

Let say that I have a table of users. I want a query that shuffle the result and only show 5 users. How do I do that in MySQL query without using any php?

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678696/random-records-mysql-php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `rand()`, but the performance is terrible

```
select * from users order by rand() limit 5; <-- slow
```

I would suggest, store list of all user id into an serialize array and cache into a disk-file. (periodically update)

So, you can un-serialize it back using PHP, and use PHP `array_rand` to pick 5 random users.

To fetch the full information, you can do

```
select * from users where user_id in(...); <-- very fast
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user FROM users
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```