# SQL Query group shuffle

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like

```
select id, item, producer from table
```

The result is like this:

```
  id          item            producer
   1          apple            A
   2          pear             A
   3          peach            A
   4          orange           B
   5          strawberry       B
   6          melon            B
```

I want to shuffle this result (order by id DESC) and get something like this

```
item            producer
strawberry       B
pear             A
orange           B
apple            A
peach            A
melon            B
```

I DON'T want to display like this:

ALL A ITEM

ALL B ITEM

ALL C ITEM...

Comment: What are you actually wanting to order by?

Comment: If Broken Heart's solution worked please select it as your answer using the tick under the number.

Comment: No, I need something more specific. I can't shuffle the id 3 with 359. I need to select the last 50 id and shuffle them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the rand function in ORDER BY like this:

```
select id, item, producer from table order by rand();
```

Comment: This is okay when i have 10 items. But what if I have 200 000 ? I don't want to display an item created 10 years ago

Comment: @user2761182 then use the where clause and your condition.

Answer (score 3):

To Shuffle the selection you can use **rand()**

The Answer for the link below contains more information.

```
 SELECT id, item, producer 
 FROM table
 ORDER BY RAND()
```

[MySQL: Shuffle a limited query result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534195/mysql-shuffle-a-limited-query-result)

Comment: Are you going to provide any code? This answer is 35% complete.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Lt_Shade is not required to provide any code. -  moreover, OP is encouraged to find a solution given information.

Comment: @Shamil [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is okay when i have 10 items. But what if I have 200 000 ? I don't want to display an item created 10 years ago

Comment: If your entries are dated you could try use a  Where clause... Or sort them by their ID's

Answer (score 2):

```
 select id, item, producer from table order by rand()
```

Use `Order BY rand()` to randomly order the results

Comment: The OP is looking for a shuffled result; not ordered.

Comment: I have revised the code having review the question